# How to get contacts by given phone number (could be partial)

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

I am working on Android 2.2, and with a given number I am trying to get all the contacts which have this number.

The given number could be partial and not the full phone number of a contact.

For example if i have two contacts:

- A with phone number: 123456
- B with phone number: 456789

when the input is 456 the query should return both of them.

I tried to use the LIKE operator on the selection, but the problem is that the numbers are stored formatted in Android (separated with '-').

Is there anyway to get unformatted phone numbers? Or is there a way to tell the query to compare the numbers but to ignore the '-'?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the REGEXP operator? Off the top of my head, something like `.*1\D*2\D*3.*` would match 123 with any number of non-digit characters in between.

Comment: How to make REGEXP work on android? It works on HTC but does not on Samsung devices nor emulator